# If $y=\ln(x)$ and the percentage error in $x$ is 5%, find the error in $y$.

Tags: calculus, error-propagation

Normally I can solve error problems easily but I am seeing this question for the first time, so a little help in understanding it would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y = \ln x  \implies dy = \frac{1}{x}dx$$ and you have $\frac{dx}{x}$in %, and $dy$ is $\cdots$

Comment: 0.05. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Slight confusion though, did you write it as $\frac{dy}{do}=lnx$? Just concerned about how you got arrived at the first equation

Comment: Yeah I differentiated to get $1/x$. I think you meant  $1/x$